# What is the keyboard shortcut to switch to Applications tab in gnome3?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

What is the keyboard shortcut to switch to Applications tab in gnome3 dash?
The Gnome dash which comes up when we press windows meta key / super key. 
I want to minimize the keyboard use.

Also how can I switch back to Windows Tab again using keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get to Applications tab using accessibility switch (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) - by hitting it several times it allows to select Applications panel. Same way to get back to windows panel.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about ctrl + alt + tab. Its more useful shortcut. It also gives option to take us to dash, search text box etc.

Answer (score 1):

I got help from IRC #gnome for this.

We can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to switch between Applications tab and Windows tab.
To select the listed applications in 'Applications' tab, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once and then press <kbd>←</kbd>.